# Find Non Used Functions?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I know you can perform a 'Find All References' on a function and you can determine if it is being used anywhere, but is there a tool that will go through all of my functions and highlight any that are not called anywhere in the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html) can do what you want. More specifically, the [*Safe Delete*](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html#Safe_Delete) command should at least faciliate the job. Although I haven't tried it, the [*Code Cleanup*](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html) tool may well do the whole thing automatically.

Comment: It does, although i believe it's for Visual Studio only.
Highly recommend it by the way

Comment: Indeed, Visual Studio only. The OP has tagged their question with VS2008 however, so I think that's no matter.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html) for this, but if you're looking for a free product, [Microsoft FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx) will identity unused public methods.

Comment: We have used ReSharper, but no longer have a license for it so I checked out FxCop and it looks like it will only work on compiled assemblies and not code.  I'll have to read more about it to make sure I am not missing something.

Comment: I didn't mention this before, but this is needed for a ASP c# web application so I don't have any compiled assemblies.  Only .cs files and .aspx.cs files